# Building a cmake project with multiple directories

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cmake

I have been given some C++ which I want to use in my project. This code comes with its own CMakeLists.txt file. To keep things neat, I want to make a new directory `foo` in my main project directory, and put this code and the CMakeLists.txt file in that directory. What I now want to know, is how do I edit the CMakeLists.txt file of my own project, to include all the source files from this other project?

Normally, I use `file(glob SOURCES *.cpp)` to create a list of all source files. Then, I would create the executable by using `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})`. However, how do I tell `SOURCES` to also include all the source files in the `foo` directory?

Now, if I use `add_subdirectory(foo)` in my main CMakeLists.txt file, then I believe this will search directory `foo` for a CMakeLists.txt file, and effectively add this to the main CMakeLists.txt file in my project. Is this correct? How can I extend this to including all the source files in this directory?

Thanks!

Comment: If the subdirectory defines a library as a target, you can link the library to an executable in your main project directory using `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: No it doesn't -- I just want to compile it all as one executable.

Comment: If all you want to do is use the sources from `foo`, then you don't even need a `CMakeLists.txt` inside `foo`. Globbing the files (`file(glob SOURCES foo/*.cpp)`) is just fine if all you want is one executable. You would use CMake if you want a higher degree of organizational structure -- that is, if you want to separate library code from executable code, then this is a great tool for that.

Comment: The reason I wanted to use two `CMakeLists.txt` files, is that the one provided with this other code is rather complex, and I'm not sure that I understand it all. Therefore, I was proposing to write my own "main" `CMakeLists.txt` file, which then calls upon the `CMakeLists.txt` file from this other project.

Comment: If all you want from `foo` are its source files, then you don't need to bother with this other `CMakeLists.txt`. Just glob the sources and be done with it. Personally I think this is the wrong way to structure a project, but you're asking how to compile everything as a single executable and this is how, absent a deeper understanding of this other `CMakeLists.txt`. If you have a particular question about that file, you can post it separately -- you'll likely get some more specific and concrete answers that way.

Comment: Actually, this other project has more than just its source files. It contains various directories itself, each with other sources files and libraries. This is why I wanted to use the `CMakeLists.txt` that came with the project. I basically just want to say "do everything exactly how this other project does it in directory `foo`, and then incorporate it all into my main project`...